# Consuming external Laravel API search variables in to my environment file

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I have two laravel projects, one have an API(laravel_1) and the other consumes it(laravel_2). 
I can call the api on Postman without problem or consume api on laravel_1 using guzzle call, but when I do the same on laravel_2 it throws error of databases if I try to call some eloquent method like 
Articles::all(); for example, so I did some tests and seems like laravel_2 try to uses his .env when calling laravel_1.

If I call the laravel_1 api from postman it returns his app name correct "Laravel_1" but if I call it from laravel_2 it's says "Laravel_2" it takes his own app.env name instead of laravel_1 how is that? Also it's the same when I try to call a database

Here is laravel_1 api code:

**web.php:**

```
Route::post('/housingAPI/getEventOffers', 'HousingApiController@getEventOffers')->name("housingApi.getEventOffers");
```

**HousingApiController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HousingApiController extends Controller
{

    public function getEventOffers(Request $request)
    {

        //todo code here with requests

        return config('app.name');

    }
}
```

and here is laravel_2 config:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', 'HousingInfoController@index')
```

**HousingInfoController.php**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\frontend;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class HousingInfoController extends Controller
    {
        public function test()
        {
            //Ofertas de eventos
            $eventOffers = $this->getAllEventOffersApiCall("H", 1, 416, "esp", '');

        }

        private function getAllEventOffersApiCall($type, $zoneId, $hotelId, $lang, $moda, $ajax = false)
        {
            $form_params = [
                'type' => $type,
                'zoneId' => $zoneId,
                'hotelId' => $hotelId,
                'lang' => $lang, 
                'moda' => $moda,
                'ajax' => $ajax
            ];

            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

            $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://laravel-api.test/housingAPI/getEventOffers', ['form_params' => $form_params]);
            $body = $response->getBody();
            dd($body->getContents());
            return json_decode($body->getContents(), true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try logging in value of your .env file in your first proyect  when you make a request for the second project. example: Log::info(env('APP_NAME'));

Comment: nothing shows in that log, but i have a return config app.name and this return his own .env on laravel_2 instead of laravel_1 name